# How do I modify my theme in response to Wordpress 3.4 changes to image caption?

Tags: wordpress

The Wordpress 3.4 release included some significant changes to how attachements with captions are handled. Specially, the mark up inserted by the attachment button has changed from this

```
[caption id="####" caption="caption goes here"]<img.....>[/caption]
```

to this

```
[caption id="####" ]<img src="abc">caption goes here[/caption]
```

As a result my theme is broken.

I understand that theme designers may need to update their themes in response. But what needs to be changed?

I have a custom theme on my wordpress site, so can't simply click to update the theme. I will need to make the necessary changes myself, but what do I need to change? What hooks or code in the template am I looking for?

Comment: As a side note, it's worthwhile looking into [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so you can make modifications and still be able to update your theme.

Comment: thanks christian, problem is I am the theme author, so wont work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Nacin recently posted about this in the [WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/caption-broken-in-new-34-posts).  Your best bet is to contact your theme author, and let them know the issue that you are having -- I'm sure they are already aware of it.

> Hello everyone.
>
> This is a deliberate change in WordPress 3.4. Instead of having caption="" as an attribute of the [caption] shortcode, WordPress inserts the caption into the main content of the shortcode, after the image and in between [caption] and [/caption].
>
> This change in 3.4 was necessary to allow for HTML in captions. But, like everything we develop, it was deliberately coded so it would be backwards compatible. Any theme using the 'img_caption_shortcode' filter to override how a caption is generated would work swimmingly, even though the format changed.
>
> If I had to guess, the common issue for all for these themes is that they call add_shortcode( 'caption', 'some_function_in_their_theme' ); to customize the caption, instead of using the aforementioned filter. This is wrong. Themes should not be doing this. If the theme you are using does this, please contact the theme author. If they disagree it is a problem with their theme, I'd be happy to explain it to them.
>
> I came here after seeing a bug report, but note that after two weeks and 2.5 million downloads, this is the only thread I've seen on this issue, so thankfully it does not appear to be adversely affecting many sites. I'm sorry if it has affected you. If you do know of any other threads, please link them to me.
>
> Thanks,
> Nacin

Comment: thanks Ryan, unfortunately I am the theme author, so no help available there :) I had noticed this post from Nacin before, but it doesn't seem to be relevant in my case. In fact, my theme has no filers interacting with the caption. I'm beginning to think this may be a plugin issue - perhaps related to lightbox or something similar. I'm still digging through code, and will post an update if I find anything. thanks for your suggestion though